# iPhone next or previous button javascript keycode

Tags: javascript, iphone

hey guys What's the iphone next or previous button javascript keycode.. in input?

Pc Tab code is 9.. but this is not working on iphone next button

Answer (score 0):

On iPhone, the "Next" button is the return key. Or, rather, the return key can be given different labels depending on context, including "Next" or "Search" or "Return".